# Android - Acessing WebService with XPath

Tags: android, xpath, service, web

I have a application and I need to parser a XML.
When I did this on Java Project, works. But, when I try to do this on the Android Project, the URL can't connect, I'm using XPath.
Code:

private static final String STRING_XML = "http://localhost:50645/WebServiceClientes.asmx/ListaReservas";

....

```
// prepare a URL to the geocoder
URL url = new URL(STRING_XML);

// prepare an HTTP connection to the geocoder
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Document geocoderResultDocument = null;
try {
  // open the connection and get results as InputSource.
  conn.connect();
  InputSource geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(conn.getInputStream());

  // read result and parse into XML Document
  geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
} finally {
  conn.disconnect(); //The debug stops here, so, Disconnect!!!
}
```

Comment: Whats your error? Permissions on manifest allow internet?  and what are you using as a phone, emulator or a real phone?

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` add more `uses-permission`: `INTERNET`

Additionally, `finally` is certainly called every time.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a localhost WebService, and to access it, need to use port 8080.